# How to use express-validator to validate form data with express-formidable in express

Tags: node.js, validation, parsing, express, formidable

I would like to use "express-formidable" to parsing form data and "express-validator" to validate form data but its not working.

### My form controller code

```
var express = require('express');
var formidable = require('express-formidable');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');

var router = express.Router();
router.use(formidable());
router.use(expressValidator());


router.all('/form-validator', function (req, res, next) {
   if (req.method.toLowerCase() == "post") {

      req.check('name', 'Invalid Name').isEmpty();
      req.check('email', 'Invalid Email').isEmail();
      var errors = req.validationErrors();
      if (errors) {
        res.send("validation failed");
      } else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(req.fields));
      }
  } else {
    res.render('pages/test');
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

### and my form is

```
 <form action="/form-validator" method="post" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="" 
           placeholder="Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
         <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" 
         id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign up</button>
  </form>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `.all` handler and testing for the HTTP method explicitly:

```
router.all('/form-validator', function (req, res, next) {
   if (req.method.toLowerCase() == "post") {
       //...
```

You can use the `.post` handler directly:

```
router.post('/form-validator', function (req, res, next) {
   //...
```

Also separating your input validation for the actual request handling can simplify your logic. You can use `next()` with or without error in your testing middleware.

You can also try `express-validation` instead or in addition to `express-validator`:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validation

because it makes the middlewares for you with a declarative style of validation logic, like e.g.:

```
{
  body: {
    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
    password: Joi.string().regex(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}/).required()
  }
}
```

It uses Joi for the validation schema definitions. See:

- https://github.com/hapijs/joi#readme